# How can my Android app open a port for listening?

Tags: android, port

I want my Android app to behave as a client and listen on a particular port.  None of the code I've tried works.  I tried [this tutorial](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-tcp-connection-tutorial.html) to create a small chat app.  The server side works fine, but the app crashes on my device. I have both my phone and server comp on VPN.

logcat text returned:

```
11-20 12:39:12.789: W/dalvikvm(12045): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4017c560)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android_port/com.example.android_port.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android_port.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android_port-1.apk]
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android_port.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android_port-1.apk]
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
11-20 12:39:12.799: E/AndroidRuntime(12045):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: whats the ClassNotFoundException here?

Comment: that tell you that com.example.android_port.MainActivity is not recognized within your app.

Comment: maybe the activity defined in manifest and the activity present in code donot match

Comment: hey thanks @nandeesh. that worked. forgot to add one activity to the manifest!